# Variable is not a CFString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Somehow the code below crashes my app:

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", dbPath, @"BAR"];
NSString *dbS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", "@", filename];
```

I've set a breakpoint at the dbS string and see that it says "variable is not A CFString." First I thought it had to do with the at-symbol, however removing it does not help.

Anyone got a clue what's going on?

Thanks!

P.s. dbPath is defined in my header file --> #define dbPath @"FOO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second string should look like this:

```
NSString *dbS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", filename];
```

Comment: It could be `NSString *dbS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filename];`, right?

Comment: @Gomathi: In this case dbS will be the same as filename, but it should have '@' prefix.